# How to group data and output in an Angular 2 template -- using pipe?

Tags: angular, group-by, pipe, ionic2

I've an Angular 2 project and am getting a list of results that I'd like to display as groups in the UI. I would like to group by one of the values that is being returned and show details for the items in the group.

Currently, I've tried to accomplish this by using [this groupby pipe](https://github.com/irondan/Angular-2-groupBy-Pipe/blob/master/groupBy.pipe.ts), but I'm having trouble getting it to work in a template.

I tried this:

```
<ion-list>
    <div *ngFor="let item of searchresults | orderBy:'item[0]'">
        <ion-item-divider sticky>{{ item[2] }}</ion-item-divider>
        <ion-item (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">{{ item[0] }}</ion-item>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

the api returns:

```
{"results":[
["Chocolade vlokken melk pak 300 gram  ","8710400407010","Albert Heijn","Hagelslag",1,2,"","701",""],
["Chocolade vlokken puur pak 300 gram  ","8710400406990","Albert Heijn","Hagelslag",1,1,"","701",""],
["Chocoladevlokken melk pak 300 gram (Kiekeboe)  ","23029217","Aldi","Hagelslag",1,2,"","612",""],
["Chocoladevlokken puur pak 300 gram (Kiekeboe)  ","23029217","Aldi","Hagelslag",1,2,"","612",""],
```

],
"api_version":0.2}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update #2:**
Added the example on <kbd>[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qndaov)</kbd>, due to references on the plunk being stale (and because StackBlitz is more friendly to use/manage).

**Update #1:**
I built a <kbd>[plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ijtRjA?p=preview)</kbd> that uses an easier to follow method to transform un-grouped data into an array of grouped objects along with an example that uses it. I also included a demo of how you could change the grouped value dynamically.

**Original Answer:**
I would suggest you do the grouping in your component rather than as a pipe for a variety of reasons, as [explained here in the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filter-pipe).

Below is some ES6 code that you can use to transform your results into grouped results, which then makes your display really easy. Slap this into a page and take a look at the grouped results in the console.

```
<script>
    const myData = {
        "results": [
            ["Chocolade vlokken melk pak 300 gram  ", "8710400407010", "Albert Heijn", "Hagelslag", 1, 2, "", "701", ""],
            ["Chocolade vlokken puur pak 300 gram  ", "8710400406990", "Albert Heijn", "Hagelslag", 1, 1, "", "701", ""],
            ["Chocoladevlokken melk pak 300 gram (Kiekeboe)  ", "23029217", "Aldi", "Hagelslag", 1, 2, "", "612", ""],
            ["Chocoladevlokken puur pak 300 gram (Kiekeboe)  ", "23029217", "Aldi", "Hagelslag", 1, 2, "", "612", ""],
        ],
        "api_version": 0.2
    };

    // transform results into grouped results
    // you can easily extract this into a function and just pass your results in and the array index you want to group on
    const groupedResults = [...myData.results.reduce((hash, result) => {
        // specify the value from each of your 'results' that you want to group on
        group = result[2];
        // Add the result to existing group if it exists, or create a new group and add it
        const currentGroup = hash.get(group) || { group, items: [] };
        currentGroup.items.push(result);
        return hash.set(group, currentGroup);
    }, new Map).values()];

    // show grouped results in the console
    console.log("New Grouped Results: ", groupedResults);

</script>
```

Comment: Can you also give a typescript example? That would be great!

Comment: I tried it and got it working: `const groupedResults = [ myData.results.reduce((hash, result) => {
                this.group = result[2];
                const currentGroup = hash.get(this.group) || { items: [] };
                currentGroup.items.push(result);
                return hash.set(this.group, currentGroup);
            }, new Map).values()];` the only thing not working is ` hash.get(this.group) || { this.group, items: [] };` so i had to replace that by  `hash.get(this.group) || { items: [] }; ` idea's how to fix?

Comment: @MaartenHeideman, I added that Plunkr, with easier to follow code to do the transform, in TypeScript, along with some example output and a quick example that allows for dynamically changing the grouping.

Comment: @MaartenHeideman, thanks for the feedback. Hope it's useful. :)

Comment: @RobMullins why i am getting this error ? results.reduce(...).values(...).slice is not a function